# Find total unique visitors based on unique id - MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregate

What is the best way to find unique visitors based on unique visitorId in this data?
I'm using Mongoose in a Nodejs/Express environment.

```json
{
        username: "jack",
        events: [
         {
           eventType: "party",
           createdAt: "2022-01-23T10:26:11.214Z",
           visitorInfo: {
                visitorId: "87654321-0ebb-4238-8bf7-87654321"
               }
         },
         {
           eventType: "party",
           createdAt: "2022-01-30T10:26:11.214Z",
           visitorInfo: {
                visitorId: "87654321-0ebb-4238-8bf7-87654321"
               }
         },
         {
           eventType: "party",
           createdAt: "2022-01-29T10:26:11.214Z",
           visitorInfo: {
                visitorId: "12345678-0ebb-4238-8bf7-12345678"
               }
         },
        {
           eventType: "party",
           createdAt: "2022-01-31T10:16:11.214Z",
           visitorInfo: {
                visitorId: "12345678-0ebb-4238-8bf7-12345678"
               }
         }
           ]

        }
```

What I'm trying:

```js
    Event.aggregate([
          { $match: "jack" },
          { $unwind: "$events" },
          { $match: { "events.eventType": "party" } },
    
          {
            $group: {
              _id: "$events.visitorInfo.visitorId",
              count: { $sum: 1 },
            },
          },
        ]);
```

This gives frequency of unique visitorIds, and I think there could be a way to use that to get unique visitors, but I'm trying to find a faster and quicker way to find number of unique visitors based on unique visitorId before going down the rabbit hole.

what I'm expecting in the end:

```json
    visitors: {
        totalVisitors: 4,
        uniqueVisitors: 2
       }
```

Appreciate any help or guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One Way is using `map` and `lodash` !

1. First get All Docs with simple `find({})`.
2. Use Map on result.
3. Using lodash.

```js
const vistorsIdsList = result.map(_ => visitorInfo.visitorId)

const vistors = {
  total: vistorsIdsList.length,
  uniq: lodash.uniq(vistorsIdsList).length
}
```

[lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash)

Comment: hmm this would just give me the number of uniqueIds, and not number of events based on uniqueIds, right? Also, not sure mixing map/lodash with mongoose queries is a good idea, especially for performance reasons. Thanks for you input thought!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually on the right track. You just need to do a `$reduce` to keep the `totalVisitors` before `$unwind`. And at the final stage, do another `$group` to get your expected result.

```js
db.event.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      username: "jack"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "totalVisitors": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$events",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.eventType",
                  "party"
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                $add: [
                  "$$value",
                  1
                ]
              },
              "else": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$events"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "events.eventType": "party"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$events.visitorInfo.visitorId",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      totalVisitors: {
        $first: "$totalVisitors"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: {
        $first: "$count"
      },
      totalVisitors: {
        $first: "$totalVisitors"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nFtFYRap3No) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you @ray. It does seem to give the correct output, I'm just wondering if the query is most performant as I'm expecting thousands and thousands of objects in the Events array.

Comment: @lisa First of all, I am not sure if the array can hold such a huge amount of entries due to the [16MB limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-BSON-Document-Size). If you are concerned about performance, you may need to properly index your collection. For your example, indexing on `username` will help with the `$match`. Indexing on `events.visitorInfo.visitorId` will help with the `$group`.

Answer (score 0):

version 1(filter):

IMHO this seems to be the best version , for best results you will need index on "username"

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $match: {
  username: "jack"
}
},
{
$project: {
  p: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$events",
      as: "item",
      cond: {
        $eq: [
          "$$item.eventType",
          "party"
        ]
       }
     }
   }
 }
 },
 {
  $unwind: "$p"
 },
 {
  $group: {
  _id: "0",
  visitors: {
    $push: "$p.visitorInfo.visitorId"
  },
  uniqueVisitors: {
    $addToSet: "$p.visitorInfo.visitorId"
   }
  }
 },
 {
  $project: {
  _id: 0,
  visitorsCount: {
    $size: "$visitors"
  },
  uniqueVisitorsCount: {
    $size: "$uniqueVisitors"
   }
  }
 }
])
```

Explained:

1. $match -> match only documents with username:jack
2. $project -> $filter only events with evetType: party
3. $unwind the filtered array to be suitable for group stage
4. $group -> visitors:[all]  , uniqueVisitors:[unique]
5. $project: visitorsCount , uniqueVisitorsCount

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aIROZIhAIo_)

version 2 ( not using filter - suitable for the atlas free tire)

```
   db.collection.aggregate([
  {
   $match: {
   username: "jack"
   }
   },
   {
    $unwind: "$events"
   },
   {
    $match: {
       "events.eventType": "party"
    }
   },
   {
    $group: {
    _id: "0",
     visitors: {
        $push: "$events.visitorInfo.visitorId"
     },
     uniqueVisitors: {
        $addToSet: "$events.visitorInfo.visitorId"
     }
    }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
       visitorsCount: {
         $size: "$visitors"
        },
        uniqueVisitorsCount: {
         $size: "$uniqueVisitors"
        }
       }
      }
      ])
```

1. $match -> match only documents with username:jack
2. unwind the $events since $filter not possible in the free tire
3. $match the eventType: party
4. $group -> visitors:[all] , uniqueVisitors:[unique]
5. $project: visitorsCount , uniqueVisitorsCount

[play ( version without filter suitable for the atlas free tire )](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZUUSG44DrpH)

Comment: Thank you @R2D2. I'm using the free tier of Atlas, unfortunately not able to use filter. But I'll keep the method in mind.

Comment: $filter was introduced in mongodb version >=3.2 , I guess Atlas is not so old :)

Comment: added one more modified option in my answer without filter better suitable for the free tire ( I found atlas intentionally do not allow filter in the free tire )

Answer (score 0):

version 3: Interesting 3th option using only project/filter/reduce ( no group & unwind )

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {
   $match: {
     username: "jack"
 }
 },
 {
   $project: {
    p: {
     $filter: {
      input: "$events",
      as: "item",
      cond: {
        $eq: [
          "$$item.eventType",
          "party"
        ]
       }
      }
     }
    }
  },
  {
   $project: {
    total: {
      $reduce: {
       input: "$p",
        initialValue: {
          visitor: [],
         uniquevisitor: []
        },
      in: {
        visitor: {
          $concatArrays: [
            "$$value.visitor",
            [
              "$$this.visitorInfo.visitorId"
            ]
          ]
        },
        uniquevisitor: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $in: [
                "$$this.visitorInfo.visitorId",
                "$$value.uniquevisitor"
              ]
            },
            "$$value.uniquevisitor",
            {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value.uniquevisitor",
                [
                  "$$this.visitorInfo.visitorId"
                ]
              ]
            }
           ]
          }
         }
       }
      }
    }
   },
  {
   $project: {
  _id: 0,
  visitorsCount: {
    $size: "$total.visitor"
  },
  uniqueVisitorsCount: {
     $size: "$total.uniquevisitor"
    }
   }
  }
 ])
```

Explained:

1. $match the docs with username: jack
2. $filter the docs with events.eventType:party
3. $reduce/$cond/$in and form two arrays with unique & all events.
4. $project to count unique and all.

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UzPOmCDDYDl)

Answer (score 0):

Version 4. Optimal with only $filter/$project ( no unwind,group )
( Idea inspired by @turvishal )

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {
 $match: {
  username: "jack"
 }
 },
 {
  $project: {
  events: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$events",
      cond: {
        $eq: [
          "$$this.eventType",
          "party"
        ]
       }
      }
     }
   }
 },
 {
  $project: {
  _id: 0,
  visitor: {
    $size: "$events.visitorInfo.visitorId"
   },
   uniquevisitor: {
    $size: {
      $setUnion: "$events.visitorInfo.visitorId"
    }
   }
  }
 }
])
```

explained:

1. $match only documents with username: jack
2. $project/$filter only eventType:"party"
3. $project visitors & unique visitors ( $setUnion )

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iOhQWt6LGRF)